# RuntimeError default_url_options host and root_url (with subdomain)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain, actionmailer, urlhelper

Each user of my app have a custom url (through subdomain) stored in db.

My request is simple, I would like to send the "user url" through a json feed, like this:

```
{user_name: "vincent", :user_url: "vincent.my_app.com"}
```

to do that I have overwrite the as_json function of user model:

```
def as_json(options={})
    {
        :user_name: self.name,
        :user_url: root_url(:subdomain => self.subdomain)
    }
end
```

I have this additionnal module (which this work great and isn't the actual problem):

```
module SubdomainHelper
def with_subdomain(subdomain)
    subdomain = (subdomain || "")
    subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
    host = ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]
    [subdomain, host].join
end

def url_for(options = nil)
    if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
        options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))
    end
    super
end
end
```

But when I get the json feed I have this error:

```
RuntimeError (Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]):
```

pointing to the "as_json" method of user model.

of course each environment implement default_url_options, in dev.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'my_app:3000'}
```

I don't understand why and how I fix it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  Somehow it seemed to be related to actionpack's url_helper and my field name.  Seems to be an issue with field names ending in *_url.  Don't fully grok why but  I had a field named login_url that I renamed to login_uri  (notice the change from l to i) and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To use the url helper `root_path` in your model I presume you are mixing in `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` or similar. These helpers always construct URLs referencing `default_url_options`. `ActionController` figures out these default options from the current request. `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` is only for mailers which have no request to intuit defaults from, not for use in models. Views delegate to the controller/mailer. Each class that mixes these helpers in must provide `default_url_options`, but generally it's just a bad idea to redefine it. Supply the URL from the controller, mailer or view.

If you really must, in your model: `delegate :default_url_options, to: ActionMailer::Base`